# How to resample with pandas in a conservative way?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I'm trying to use pandas dataframe/series to store measurements. These are used as inputs for a thermodynamical simulation. So when resampling the sum of heat(/energy) and the values of temperature should stay constant.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start_date = '2015-01-01 '
my_timing = '60T'
my_ts_index = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=6, freq=my_timing, name='Time')
# read from a csv or sql data base
Heat = [120,200,210,0 ,50, 180]
Temperature = [23.2, 19.1, 15.3, 25.2, 20.1, 0.0]
data=np.array([(Heat),
               (Temperature)])
columnNames=['Heat','Temperature']
my_ts=pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(data),columns=columnNames,index=my_ts_index)
print(my_ts)
# GUI checks if len(my_ts)%new_timestep==0
# increase frequency
tmp=my_ts.resample('25T').mean()
tmp['Heat']=tmp['Heat'].fillna(0)
tmp['Temperature']=tmp['Temperature'].ffill()
print(tmp)               
# reduce frequency
tmp=tmp.resample('60T').agg({'Heat':lambda x:np.sum(x),'Temperature':np.average})
print(tmp)
tmp=my_ts.resample('75T').agg({'Heat':lambda x:np.sum(x),'Temperature':np.average})
print(tmp)
```

Output:

```
                      Heat  Temperature
Time                                   
2015-01-01 00:00:00  120.0         23.2
2015-01-01 01:00:00  200.0         19.1
2015-01-01 02:00:00  210.0         15.3
2015-01-01 03:00:00    0.0         25.2
2015-01-01 04:00:00   50.0         20.1
2015-01-01 05:00:00  180.0          0.0

                     Heat  Temperature
Time                                   
2015-01-01 00:00:00  120.0         23.2
2015-01-01 00:25:00    0.0         23.2
2015-01-01 00:50:00  200.0         19.1
2015-01-01 01:15:00    0.0         19.1
2015-01-01 01:40:00  210.0         15.3
2015-01-01 02:05:00    0.0         15.3
2015-01-01 02:30:00    0.0         15.3
2015-01-01 02:55:00    0.0         25.2
2015-01-01 03:20:00    0.0         25.2
2015-01-01 03:45:00   50.0         20.1
2015-01-01 04:10:00    0.0         20.1
2015-01-01 04:35:00    0.0         20.1
2015-01-01 05:00:00  180.0          0.0     

                      Heat  Temperature
Time                                   
2015-01-01 00:00:00  320.0    21.833333
2015-01-01 01:00:00  210.0    17.200000
2015-01-01 02:00:00    0.0    18.600000
2015-01-01 03:00:00   50.0    22.650000
2015-01-01 04:00:00    0.0    20.100000
2015-01-01 05:00:00  180.0     0.000000

                      Heat  Temperature
Time                                   
2015-01-01 00:00:00  320.0        21.15
2015-01-01 01:15:00  210.0        15.30
2015-01-01 02:30:00    0.0        25.20
2015-01-01 03:45:00   50.0        20.10
2015-01-01 05:00:00  180.0         0.00
```

Which operations should be used to resample data to higher frequency and back to the original without loosing anything?
(See: Output 1&3+conservative properties in Output 2 of energy and temperature still have to hold)
How to set the mean/average/sum to start at the 2nd value so the first stays untouched for initial value reasons? Or inother words: How to assign the mean to the next not the previous hour?
(See: Output 4 first value pair)